# Requests can only be made in the logged in state, not the sentclientrequest state error comes only in loop, what's solution for this?

Tags: node.js, sql-server

```
...

var transaction = await new sql.Transaction(conn);
        
transaction.begin().then(async function () {
             
      var request = new sql.Request(transaction);

      async.eachSeries(cityLedgerSettlementAgainstRequset, async function(element){
                     
          request = new sql.Request(transaction);   
          request.input('date', sql.Date, date);
          request.input('ledgerId', sql.VarChar, element.LedgerId);
          await request.execute('PartyBalanceAdd');  

      });
});
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You're calling

```
var request = new sql.Request(transaction);
```

outside the loop, then again inside it.